# Is subset sum with a fixed target sum NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, decision-problem

I've read that subset sum is NP-complete. What happens when I change the decision problem to look for a  constant number? So the decision problem would look like this:

> Input:
>   A collection of nonnegative integers A and a nonnegative integer b,
>
> Output:
>   Boolean value indicating whether some subset of 
>   the collection sums to **10**

Would this still be NP-complete? I don't believe you would be able to reduce every other NP-complete problem to it.

Comment: This is polytime solvable when the target for the sum is a fixed constant. This follows by [the pseudopolynomial-time algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) for subset sum.

Comment: What is $b$ for?

Answer (score 5):

We can throw away all zeroes in $A$. If a subset of $A$ sums to $10$, then this subset contains at most $10$ elements. There are at most $10|A|^{10}$ such non-empty subsets, so we can go over all of them in polynomial time.

Answer (score -3):

Subset sum problem with only one number is probably not NP-complete, because there is a polynomial algorithm that solves this problem.
If it is NP-complete, then P=NP.